# How to format sql table using values as column

Tags: postgresql, crosstab

I have the following result :

```
-------------------------
| dept | Active request |
-------------------------
| AFG  | 3              |
| AGO  | 4              |
| KMN  | 1              |
| MOL  | 1              |
| POD  | 2              |
| SUD  | 2              |
-------------------------
```

How can I tranform it to have something like

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| Title          | AFG | AGO | KMN | MOL | POD | SUD | TOTAL | 
--------------------------------------------------------------
| Active Request | 3   | 4   | 1   | 1   | 2   | 2   | 13    |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is my fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b51a03/3

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? You can use PIVOT if you know the columns in advance, but that's no alternative to client-side formatting or reporting. SQL is a query language, not a report builder. A query's columns must be known at the time the query gets compiled.

Comment: `I have the following result` ... you really should have included the data from your original table.  It is not acceptable to just drop a Fiddle link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a single pivot query:

```sql
SELECT
    'Active Request' AS Title,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE dept = 'AFG') AS AFG,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE dept = 'AGO') AS AGO,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE dept = 'KMN') AS KMN,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE dept = 'MOL') AS MOL,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE dept = 'POD') AS POD,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE dept = 'SUD') AS SUD,
    COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM req
WHERE active;
```

Comment: I got "Active request" not found

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the postgresql crosstab tablefunc.

You can find an detailed explanation at: [Pivot Tables in PostgreSQL Using the Crosstab Function](https://learnsql.com/blog/creating-pivot-tables-in-postgresql-using-the-crosstab-function/)